# Why any URL end with inco.in redirect to same page?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, redirect

You can check this by taking any URL and append it with `inco.in` and enter it in search bar then you will get same page . Why and how it's happening ?
This is an image of redirected web page . 
[image: Web page Image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably,

The webpage owner `inco.in` use simple .htaccess redirect

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^inco.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://inco.in/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: maybe they have a kind of subdomain landing page that look like the one on the picture. And every time you try to access subdomains, you are getting redirected like that